# how to iterate over all documents in mongodb collection, one document at a time?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a multiple documents in a collection. I want to extract data from one document, do stuff, then go to the next document and repeat the process.

Here's a pseudo code to explain what I mean:

```
while True:

  doc = companylist.find_one()
  companyName = doc["Company Name"]
  **do stuff**
  ***go to next document in companylist***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the code below:

`for data in companylist.find():
     Logic`

This is nothing but creating a cursor and iterating over the same.